# How to enter unique associations only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Running the following code to add an association enters multiple entries each time the code is ran:

```
store.categories << category
```

Is there a way to make it only enter unique associations between the two models in the db?

Comment: Why? Your join table by definition is going to need the store and category IDs, so what are you gaining by not using these models in the first place?

Comment: I have the models -- I was just wondering if I will be required to have a model for the joining table as well.

Comment: Since the associations themselves work with just the relationships specified in the 2 core models.

Comment: No, you generally do not need the join model. You'll end up doing things like `store.categories << category` and Rails will assign the values in the join table for you.

Comment: Will that actually save the record in the joining table in the db?

Comment: @jdl: That works with one problem -- if the same code is ran again, it insert a duplicate entry in the association table. Is there a way to have it only enter one unique association?

Comment: If you were to create the join model you could just add a uniqueness validator on it, like so: `validate :store_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :category_id}`. This will however make your application throw an error if you try to enter a duplicate relationship.

Comment: is there a way to IGNORE duplicates without throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ignoring** duplicates only seem to work with begin and rescue logic:

```
begin
  stores.categories << category
rescue
  puts "Duplicate entry ignored"
end
```

Comment: Are you using any validations on your join model?

Answer (score 6):

Directly from the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), hope it helps:

```
class Person
  has_many :readings
  has_many :posts, :through => :readings, :uniq => true
end
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships, but definitely handy for any association with `:through`

Comment: In the documentation also exists `:uniq => true` for HABTM relationships (see `4.4.2.19 :uniq` in the rails guides)