# Make sure has_many :through association is unique on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

If you are saving a has_many :through association at record creation time, how can you make sure the association has unique objects. Unique is defined by a custom set of attributes.

Considering:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_roles
   has_many :roles, through: :user_roles

   before_validation :ensure_unique_roles

   private
   def ensure_unique_roles
      # I thought the following would work:
      self.roles = self.roles.to_a.uniq{|r| "#{r.project_id}-#{r.role_id}" }
      # but the above results in duplicate, and is also kind of wonky because it goes through ActiveRecord assignment operator for an association (which is likely the cause of it not working correctly)

     # I tried also:
     self.user_roles = []
    self.roles = self.roles.to_a.uniq{|r| "#{r.project_id}-#{r.role_id}" }

     # but this is also wonky because it clears out the user roles which may have auxiliary data associated with them
   end
 end
```

What is the best way to validate the user_roles and roles are unique based on arbitrary conditions on an association?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this, especially if you're using a relational db, is to create a unique multi-column index on `user_roles`.

`add_index :user_roles, [:user_id, :role_id], unique: true`

And then gracefully handle when the role addition fails:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def try_add_unique_role(role)
    self.roles << role
  rescue WhateverYourDbUniqueIndexExceptionIs
    # handle gracefully somehow
    # (return false, raise your own application exception, etc, etc)
  end
end
```

Relational DBs are designed to guarantee referential integrity, so use it for exactly that. Any ruby/rails-only solution will have race conditions and/or be really inefficient.

If you want to provide user-friendly messaging and check "just in case", just go ahead and check:

```
already_has_role = UserRole.exists?(user: user, role: prospective_role_additions)
```

You'll still have to handle the potential exception when you try to persist role addition, though.

Comment: Sure, always good to have final say at the db level, but then the application would throw an exception if this occurred. I'd still like to sanitize before sending to the database and avoid the exception flow on the common case.

Comment: You mean like https://stackoverflow.com/a/8034383? It requires an extra query to the other table anyways, and in the 1% case, you'll still have to deal with the exception. Why not write your own update method that catches this particular exception case and handles it gracefully, thereby covering 100% of cases?

Comment: Validations aren't 100% effective without indexes at the db level.  IMO best answer.

Comment: @Kache - putting uniq: true on the association doesn't solve the problem of assignment, only on query. overriding update is possible, but imagine how catching the exception would have to be implemented. You'd have to specifically catch a unique index AR exception, and then still determine if the exception is for this specific case, AND THEN STILL de-duplicate and assign to the association. Much simpler to have a before_validation that does this. But still the question remains: how to de-duplicate an association?

Answer (score 2):

Just do a multi-field validation. Something like:

```
class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id,
            :role_id, 
            :project_id,
            presence: true

  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:project_id, :role_id] }            

  belongs_to :user, :project, :role
end
```

Something like that will ensure that a user can have only one role for a given project - if that's what you're looking for.

As mentioned by Kache, you probably *also* want to do a db-level index. The whole migration might look something like:

```
class AddIndexToUserRole < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :user_roles, [:user_id, :role_id, :project_id], unique: true, name: :index_unique_field_combination
  end
end
```

The `name:` argument is optional but can be handy in case the concatenation of the field names gets too long (and throws an error).

Comment: thanks. But this is good for validation errors, however, the question is really about how to sanitize before validation, and not simply error out. If someone puts the same role twice, I *could* throw an error and make them fix it, or I could provide a good user experience and de-duplicate it for them.

Comment: If you do something like `valid?`, you won't throw an error and can provide specific feedback to your user based on the nature of the error. That's a pretty standard SOP. You *could* do some manual checks yourself before trying `valid?` or `save` or `create` or whatever, but then you're just replicating ActiveRecord functionality and I'm not sure why you would do that.