# Rails 5: How do I avoid multiple rows being created for single object with has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model and a `ContactForm` model. A user can have multiple contact forms and, likewise, a contact form can have multiple users.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contact_form_userships
  has_many :contact_forms, through: :contact_form_userships
end

class ContactForm < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contact_form_userships
  has_many :users, through: :contact_form_userships
end

class ContactFormUsership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contact_form
end
```

I'm relating the two models via a join table called `ContactFormUsership`.

I had assumed that a user could only be added once to the list of users belonging to a contact form. But I have discovered that this is not the case. If I add a user to a contact form multiple times, multiple rows are created for that user:

```
contact_form = ContactForm.create
user = users(:user_1)

10.times do
  contact_form.users << user
end

> contact_form.users.count
=> 10

> contact_form.users.map(&:id).uniq.count
=> 1
```

How do I ensure that only one row is created for the user, no matter how many times I push it on `contact_form.users`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make sure has\_many :through association is unique on creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112151/make-sure-has-many-through-association-is-unique-on-creation)

Comment: Are you getting any mileage from the `ContactFormUsership` class?  If it doesn't have any attributes, meaning it's just a mapping of `contact_form_id` to `user_id`, then the behavior you're looking for is called a "has and belongs to many" relationship, which is covered in the Rails Guides: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: As in the Question linked by @JackBracken in his comment, you should add a uniqueness constraint in the join table, made by the couple of the two foreign_keys. meaning the entries are unique considered together. It can be done also with a custom validation, but it is better done with the suggestion in the answer linked.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a uniqueness validation to your ContactFormUsership:

```
validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :contact_form_id }
```